# Passing Values from datagridview to listview

Tags: c#, vb.net

Please help me. How can I pass values form data grid view to list view using C# object oriented?

please help me convert to C# .Thanks in advance.

```
        Dim i As Integer
        i = dtgShift.CurrentRow.Index
        shiftID = dtgShift.Item(0, i).Value
        txtShiftName.Text = dtgShift.Item(1, i).Value
        dblInputShiftHrs.Text = dtgShift.Item(2, i).Value
        Dim lvitem As ListViewItem
        If dtgShift.Item(3, i).Value.ToString <> "" Then
            chkMon.Checked = True
            lvitem = lvSched.Items.Add("Monday")
            lvitem.SubItems.Add(dtgShift.Item(3, i).Value.ToString)
            lvitem.SubItems.Add(dtgShift.Item(4, i).Value.ToString)
        End If
```

Comment: Need more info. Winforms, WPF or ASP.NET?

Comment: thank sir @Irshad . winforms . I want to pass value from datagridview to listview .

Answer (score 0):

According to your VB code given this is how C# lloks like;

```
int i = dtgShift.CurrentRow.Index;
shiftID = dtgShift[0, i].Value;
txtShiftName.Text = dtgShift[1, i].Value.ToString();
dblInputShiftHrs.Text = dtgShift[2, i].Value.ToString();
ListViewItem lvitem = default(ListViewItem);

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dtgShift[3, i].Value.ToString()))
{
     chkMon.Checked = true;
     lvitem = lvSched.Items.Add("Monday");
     lvitem.SubItems.Add(dtgShift[3, i].Value.ToString());
     lvitem.SubItems.Add(dtgShift[4, i].Value.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks sir @Irshad 
. I made it

```
        ListViewItem listview;
        if(_schedule.MondayFrom != "")
        {
            checkBoxMon.Checked = true;
            listview = listViewEditSchedule.Items.Add("Monday");
            listview.SubItems.Add(_schedule.MondayFrom);
            listview.SubItems.Add(_schedule.MondayTo);
        }
```